# Is there a way to get an NPC's RefID in game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When using the console to affect NPC characters you always need their RefID. I always get this on one of the two Skyrim wikis because the following help command returns only their BaseID:

```
help <npc name> 4
```

Is there a way to get their RefID through the in game help search?

Comment: Try help <npc name> 0. To the best of my knowledge that should return everything containing the npc's name, including the RefID.

Comment: Yay for not reading the question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can either get their RefID by clicking on them with the console open to target them, which should display their RefID at the top of the screen ([source: UESPWiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console)), or by looking at an exhaustive list like [this one](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-NPCs) (also UESPWiki).

I haven't heard of any other ways but will update my answer if I find anything.

Comment: This is as good an answer as there's going to be, wish I had more votes.

Comment: to expand: you must click on the npc which displays their RefID at the top of the consolen but it is displaying it because clicking also performs a Prid command with the thing you just clicked. very handy!

Comment: Adam, good point, I've put that in my answer

Comment: Do some NPCs just [not have one](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Torkild)?

Comment: @Hashbrown, yes some NPC do not have a REF ID. This commonly occurs when they are general NPC, such as Guards, and not a specific NPC, such as Ysolda

Answer (score 18):

If you can't see or click the NPC you want to get the RefID but you know its name, then on the console type "**save funclist 1**". It will open a txt file with every refID in your save game, just search for its name.

Comment: this is really cool, the only thing that helped me find Serana's refID, without knowing where she is, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me find my follower...who was in a jail for some reason :D

Comment: This should be the flagged answer.