# I lost my Follower, Frea

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

So I was running around some places, and I had done lots and lots of things without saving.
And then I noticed Frea was gone missing.
She's carrying a lot of my stuff and I don't know her ref ID.
How can i get her back?

I have all the DLC's.

Comment: ref id - 017A0D

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: getting a NPC's Ref Id** ([credits to TormentedSouL](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/161358/64871))

- Open the console window
- Type `save funclist 1` , this will open a txt file with a lot of data.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> to **Search** for the npc by name. *(This case, Frea)*
- You should find 2 references for the name, one with the Base ID and one with the Ref ID. *(base ID is the same ID that you get when you do `help "<npc name>"`)*
- The IDs are the number/letter combination in the left column of the file. *(they can be numbers only)*

[image]

---

**Step 2: Retrieve NPC**

- Open the console window.
- Type `player.moveto <ref ID>` to teleport yourself to the NPC.
- **OR** type `prid <ref ID>` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then `moveto player` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>; To bring the NPC to you.

If the NPC is dead, resurrect them after locating the corpse.
Click their body and open the console window to type in `resurrect`

**Warning:** this will reset their inventory and you will have lost the items.